# apply filter on image pixels on dynamic world dataset to get pixels having specific index value in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, filter

While selecting pixels having specific values using following code,

```
////////////////// Dynamic World ////////////////////////
var dw = ee.ImageCollection('GOOGLE/DYNAMICWORLD/V1')
             .filterDate('2023-01-01', '2023-03-31')
             .filterBounds(geometry);

// Select label layer
var classification = dw.select('label');
var dwComposite = classification.reduce(ee.Reducer.mode());
var water = dwComposite.filter(ee.Filter.or(
  ee.Filter.eq('label_mode', 0),
  ee.Filter.eq('label_mode', 8)
));
```

I'm having the following error,

> Line 17: dwComposite.filter is not a function

please help me to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I got the desired output by following corrections,

```
var water =dwComposite.eq(0).or(dwComposite.eq(8))
Map.addLayer(water, {}, 'water');
```

Thanks.